# How to convert numbers to characters without chr() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a mission to convert numbers to ASCII characters without `chr()` function I have the code of my teacher but I didn't find some idea

```
str1=''
for i in range(0x3B1,0x3CA):
    str1+=str(hex(i))
    str1=str1.replace('0x','\\u0')
print(str1)
```

Comment: *Why* do you have this mission? Is it homework? Search for "ASCII code table" and hard-code it into your program.

Comment: Best of luck for your mission. My wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the 10 digits, convert them to strings and then use the ord() function and map them to ascii code.

```
for number in range(10):
    print ord(str(number))
```

Then confirm the result using the  [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I mean that I need create script of `chr()` function without use the same function for exemple take number and convert it to his unicode without `chr()` with number like 97 to convert a